# MySQL stored procedure where clause is not filtering records

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, guid

I'm working with a db where the keys are all binary(16), essentially stored as a GUID with a couple of the values flipped around. I have a simple stored procedure where I want to filter out a single by ID.

```
delimiter //
create procedure select_item_by_id (
    in id binary(16)
)
begin
    select
        `id`,
        `name`
    from
        `item`
    where
        `id` = id;
end //
delimiter ;
```

When I fire it like so, it pulls back all the records in the table, no filtering is done:

```
call select_item_by_id(unhex('11e7deb1b1628696ad3894b2c0ab197a'));
```

However, if I run it manually...it filters the record exactly as expected:

```
select
    `id`,
    `name`
from
    `item`
where
    `id` = unhex('11e7deb1b1628696ad3894b2c0ab197a');
```

I even tried passing in a string/chars and doing the unhex inside of the sproc, but that pulls zero results:

```
delimiter //
create procedure select_item_by_id (
    in id char(32)
)
begin
    select
        `id`,
        `name`
    from
        `item`
    where
        `id` = unhex(id);
end //
delimiter ;

call select_item_by_id('11e7deb1b1628696ad3894b2c0ab197a');
```

Pretty weird. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: rename your id parameter in procedure so there is no ambivalence as to which parameter your query  uses...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that `WHERE id = id` is always evaluating to true, as it might be checking if the row's `id` is equal to itself. Rename the parameter to something else.

Comment: Bah! Figures it was something lame. I'm new to mysql, so I assumed `quoting` the field would have handled that.

Comment: It's good practice to avoid introducing ambiguity in your code - but no worries! Oftentimes SQL languages will catch ambiguities in a query, but not always in stored procedures.

Comment: ^^^ "_Structured Query Languages Languages_"

Long day.

Comment: Normally would, but I come from years of mssql where you can get away w/ this sort of thing. Learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 2):

Rename the parameter of your proc:

```
create procedure select_item_by_id (
    in idToTest char(32)
)
```

and use

```
    where
        `id` = idToTest;
```

to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Appreciate it!!